# Problema con función en Javascript y atributo 'onkeyup' de input HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Cuando intento introducir datos siempre me manda este error `(HTMLInputElement.onkeyup)`

No sé como se hace para asignar datos a una función de Javascript que contenga `arrays` del `input`.

```html
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txt1[]" onkeyup="validar(this.form)" />
    <input type="text" name="txt2[]" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validar(form) {
  if(form.txt1.value==1){
  
         form.txt2.disabled=false
  
  }
  else{
        form.txt2.disabled=true
  }
  
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un pequeño error en la forma en que tratas de capturar tus elementos del `form`.

Si bien `this.form` hace referencia a tu formulario, los elementos de dicho formulario se almacenan en un `array` llamado `elements` que pertenece a dicho objeto.

Luego cada elemento tiene sus propiedades y métodos a los cuales puedes acceder (por ejemplo usando la notación de punto: `form.elements[i].value`, donde el índice `i` indica la posición en el `array` de dicho elemento).

Una forma en la que puedes hacer lo que te propones usando tu lógica es la siguiente:

```js
function validar(form) {
  form.elements[1].disabled = form.elements[0].value == '1'? false : true;
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txt1" onkeyup="validar(this.form)" />
    <input type="text" name="txt2" disabled/>
</form>
```

Sin embargo, no es recomendable exponer el nombre de la función Javascript en tu código HTML. Para ello puedes usar el método [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) de tu elemento.

Este ejemplo es sencillo debido a que tu formulario solo contiene 2 elementos, por lo tanto es fácil conocer los índices de los elementos dentro del arreglo, sin embargo en formularios grandes y complejos usar el arreglo de elementos puede ser un poco tedioso.

Dado que la validación la harás sobre un elemento `input` específico, lo recomendable es agregar un atributo `id` a cada elemento `input` y trabajar sobre dichos elementos.

Un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementarlo usando estas recomendaciones es el siguiente:

```js
function validar(event) { // declaramos nuestra funcion de validación
  txt2.disabled = txt1.value === '1' ? false : true;
}

let txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1'); // <- almacenamos el primer input
let txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2'); // <- almacenamos el segundo input

txt1.onkeyup = validar;  // <- usamos la función validar para el evento onkeyup
```

```html
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
    <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" disabled/>
</form>
```

Con esto ya tienes la misma funcionalidad sin exponer nada de código JS en el HTML.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo
Hago una consulta:
Como puedo hacer para que detecte si el input empieza con determinado caracter habilite el otro input y si no empieza con ese caracter no se habilite Gracias espero puedan ayudarme